# Connection Refused - ActionMailer with gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25
```

This is the error that I receive when I am trying to send an email using ActionMailer.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'faker'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3'
gem 'instagram'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'amazon-ses-mailer'



group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false, :group => :test
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "joemarion.io",
    user_name: ENV['gmail_username'],
    password: ENV['gmail_password'],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }

end
```

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "support@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def contact_us(pending_message)
    @message = pending_message

    mail to: "joemarion.io@gmail.com",
        subject: "New message from JoeMarion.io!"
  end
end
```

I have followed a couple tutorials now and I keep running into this problem. I have seen a couple others on SO have this error, but they were due to incorrect settings (most of which they were setting their smtp's up in an initializer, but when they moved it back into development it worked).

I am able to establish a connection to Gmail's server via the command line.

At this point I am starting to get boggled as to what I need to change to fix this. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:
after running:

telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

```
Trying 64.233.180.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP u68sm13502513oia.22 - gsmtp
```

telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

```
Trying 64.233.180.109
```

before timing out.

Comment: Try `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000", protocol: "http"  }`

Comment: That didn't work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In development.rb add this:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

After, try change port 587 to 25, and run:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

And see the messages, if does not work, change for

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

And a detail, in development:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   ...
   domain: "localhost"
}
```

On production is ok use domain: "joemarion.io", development I preffer use localhost.

Comment: Tried both and added responses. Still no luck connecting. And I was switching between localhost and the domain. I have changed these settings so many times based on other threads I don't even remember the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the security level of your google account to see if the connection refusal is from google side. Following link should provide more information:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

I did not encounter this problem myself in rails, I encountered it while using javamail, but its worth a try.

Comment: I was wondering if this could be the case, but unfortunately it wasn't